# Double rendering error in Rails while using wicked pdf gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, pdf

In my rails app, I am creating an API that accepts order details from other devices and generates pdf which is then uploaded to the AWS.I am using wicked_pdf gem to generate the pdf and aws-sdk to upload data to Aws. The controller code is as follows.

```
def order_invoice
  response = Hash.new
  result = Hash.new
  if params[:order] && params[:order][:txnid] && 
     params[:no_of_copies] && params[:order][:total_amount]!= 0
    @order = params[:order]
              ...
    @no_of_copies = params[:no_of_copies]
    invoice = create_pdf
    response['result'] = invoice
    response.merge! ApiStatusList::OK
  else
    response.merge! ApiStatusList::INVALID_REQUEST
  end 
  render :json => response
end

def create_pdf
  pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
          render_to_string(template: 'invoices/generate_invoice.pdf.erb'))

  send_data(pdf, filename: params[:order][:txnid] + ".pdf" ,
                 type: 'application/pdf',
                 disposition: 'attachment', print_media_type: true)
  save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs', @order['txnid'] + ".pdf")
  File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
    file << pdf
    filename = @order['txnid'] + ".pdf"
  end
  file_name =  @order['txnid'] + ".pdf"
  upload = Invoice.upload(save_path, file_name)
end
```

While generating and uploading the pdf I get the following error

> AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in Api::V0::InvoiceApiController#order_invoice
>   Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

I need to give the link of the uploaded pdf as response. I know the error is because of using two renders here. However I dont know how to overcome the error. Can anyone help me to tweak and correct the code. Newbie in rails and api's.

Comment: So, you want to send the pdf as well as the son in response of a single request?

Comment: @Jagdeep Singh Yes exactly !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you render repsonse 2 times:

1. via `send_data` in `#create_pdf`
2. via `render :json => response` in action

UPD:

After discussion, we came to this - you don't need content of the file in your response, only link to AWS.

So, to fix this just remove your `send_file` call:

```
def create_pdf
  # render_to_string doesn`t mean "render response",
  # so it will not end up "double render"
  pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
          render_to_string(template: 'invoices/generate_invoice.pdf.erb'))

  # send_file renders response to user, which you don't need
  # this was source of "double render" issue
  # so we can just remove it
  save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs', @order['txnid'] + ".pdf")
  File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
    file << pdf
    filename = @order['txnid'] + ".pdf"
  end
  file_name =  @order['txnid'] + ".pdf"
  upload = Invoice.upload(save_path, file_name)
end
```

Comment: I am aware of that. I don't know how to overcome them. The one in send_data is as per the syntax I found for wicked_pdf. The other is rendering api response. Can you show me a way to overcome the error

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed last paragraph in your question. Do you need to send only link, or you want to also send content of the file in the same response?

Comment: I am returning the link for the pdf stored in Aws in upload method. I want to send the same link as a response after creating and uploading of pdf.

Comment: If you don't want to send content of the file you just need to remove your `send_data` call, aren't you? You will create pdf and upload it to `s3`. Then you will return link to it from `#upload` method and place it into `response['result']`

Comment: Alright but how does it eliminates the need to use two rendering here?Can you elaborate.How should I fix the code?

Comment: Actually here I am sending data to the generate_invoice.pdf.erb  file to generate the pdf

Comment: @MaheshMesta updated my answer. Is this what you need?